How to display a sprite in pixi js
I'm using pixi js v8.1.1. I am able to make a graphic clickable. I tried wrapping it in a sprite like below, but then it doesn't show on the page.
renderer = await PIXI.autoDetectRenderer({});
const app = new Application();
await app.init({ background: '#8effe5', width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight, antialias: true });
document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);

let x = 0, y = 0;

const diamond = new Sprite(
  renderer.generateTexture(
    new Graphics()
      .beginFill(0xffffff)
      .drawPolygon([x, (tileHeight / 2) + y, (TILE_WIDTH / 2) + x, y, TILE_WIDTH + x, (tileHeight / 2) + y, (TILE_WIDTH / 2) + x, tileHeight + y])
      .endFill()
      .stroke({ width: 2, color: 0x000000 })
  )
);

app.stage.addChild(diamond);

If I try putting the graphics in a container instead along w/ container.on('click', () => {}), it doesn't fire when clicked.

It worked to use a container like this:
const container = new Container();
container.addChild(g);
container.interactive = true;
container.addListener(`click`, () => {
  console.log(`yoyo`);
});

